# Caption of a grid in a windows universal project

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am trying to set a caption (something like the caption of a html table control) for my grid control but I am not seeing any property related to that. Am I missing something ?

Currently I am thinking to set the grid caption using another `TextBlock` control having the same alignment with the grid... but this seems to get complicated for such a simple thing.

Do you know, is there another way to set the caption of a grid in a universal windows project ?

Comment: Please, read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another row to your grid. Then add a TextBlock to the last row for the caption.  Set the Grid ColumnSpan property, for the TextBlock, to span all of the columns in your grid.

Here is an example:

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="White" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Fill="White" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Fill="Black" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Fill="White" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Fill="White" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Fill="White" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Fill="Black" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Fill="White" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Text="This is a Caption" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I am thinking to set the grid caption using another TextBlock control having the same alignment with the grid... but this seems to get complicated for such a simple thing.

This is an acceptable solution, Mike Jablonski has provided a sample. If you need to ensure **reusability**, you can create a **UserControl** which using TextBlock control to show Caption, registering a dependency property is a good way to set "Caption" for this UserControl, see [Dependency properties overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185583)